# Google AdSense stuck on We're Reviewing Your Site

Tags: google-adsense

I am a new user to AdSense.  I received an email on Feb 5th 2017 saying "your application has been successfully reviewed".  When I click on the "Get Started Now" button and login to AdSense, it says "We're reviewing your site" and all other options are disabled.

It is now Feb 20th and I am unable to progress.  The code is pasted into my site and I am getting traffic but can't see to go any further.

Please help.

I tried asking for help on Google forums too but that doesn't work either!

Comment: you have to share your url so i can check it .In most cases adsense account stuck on review account due to ad code is not inserted properly. So review your ad code implementation first